# How to access the content of the jar during runtime?

Tags: java

How can I access the content of the jar file which has been started. I want to create a big jar file which contains everything I need and then during runtime I want to copy some files of my jar into an external folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You want [`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Example:

```
InputStream config =
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

The files in the JAR are not accessible as files, so you must use getResourceAsStream to read them. See [access files and folders in executable jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611704/access-files-and-folders-in-executable-jars) how to access the files within the jar.

Following, you use the inputstream to write the files onto the file system.
See:

- [Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can access any file via the ClassPath using the classloader.  Start with Class.getResourceAsStream